# TTImageView shows black image (OR: replacement for TTImageView)

Tags: iphone, asynchronous, three20, image-caching

I'm using Three20's TTImageView for it's async image loading + caching.

I've noticed this issue a bunch of times where an image will show up as completely black, and never finish loading.  Here's an example of what I'm seeing:

http://screencast.com/t/7O7fnedX5Z2

So...basically I'm wondering if this is a bug in three20, and if so, how I might go about fixing it (is there a patch out there that might fix it)...OR:

Is there a good TTImageView replacement that performs async image loading + caching?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was seeing the following in my log:

TTRequestLoader connection:didReceiveResponse:: TTDASSERT failed: 0 == _queue.maxContentLength || contentLength <=_queue\
.maxContentLength

(one for each failed image)

After that, a little bit of googling rendered:

http://groups.google.com/group/three20/browse_thread/thread/8bfac3654a6d9674/caf797f265445971?pli=1

> Jeff Verkoeyen:
>
> The comment immediately before that
>   assert should shed some light on the 
>   situation.

```
  // If you hit this assertion it's because a massive file is about to be downloaded. 
  // If you're sure you want to do this, add the following line to your app delegate startup 
  // method. Setting the max content length to zero allows anything to go through. If you just 
  // want to raise the limit, set it to any positive byte size. 
  // [[TTURLRequestQueue mainQueue] setMaxContentLength:0]
```